# Play lock screen slideshow in Windows 8 from RSS (RequestSetImageFeedAsync error)

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-8.1, slideshow, lockscreen

I'm trying to use method `public static IAsyncOperation<SetImageFeedResult> RequestSetImageFeedAsync(Uri syndicationFeedUri)` to play lock screen slideshow from external Uri in Windows 8.
When I set this https://urzagatherer.azure-mobile.net/api/wallpapers RSS Uri  from this tutorial http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/11/13/what-a-cool-feature-controling-the-windows-8-1-lock-screen-slide-show.aspx, and open "Change PC Settings", I always see message: "You need more than one picture to show in your slideshow", like on image below and slideshow doesn't play: [image]

Here is my code:

```
SetImageFeedResult result = await LockScreen.RequestSetImageFeedAsync(new Uri("https://urzagatherer.azure-mobile.net/api/wallpapers")); 
if (result == SetImageFeedResult.Success) 
{ 
    AddImageFeedScenarioOutputText.Text = "Called RequestSetImageFeedAsync: the specified URL was set as the default."; 
} 
else if (result == SetImageFeedResult.ChangeDisabled) 
{ 
    AddImageFeedScenarioOutputText.Text = "Called RequestSetImageFeedAsync: call succeeded but group policy has the lock screen image slide show turned off."; 
} 
else // (result == SetImageFeedResult.UserCanceled) 
{ 
    AddImageFeedScenarioOutputText.Text = "Called RequestSetImageFeedAsync: the specified URL was not set as the default."; 
}
```

What is wrong in my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code on windows 8.1 and must say its working [image: perfectly] without throwing any error. It asked for permission to change my Lockscreen and had to select allow

Comment: It's very interesting. Did you check that slideshow plays?

Comment: Yes it was playing fine

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'll check my code on another PC.

Comment: I basically created an app wrote ur code commented out AddImageFeedScenarioOutputText.Text lines as didnt create a textblock/textbox and ran then Inside app it asked for permission and when I allowed then using breakpoint got success result.

Comment: Also my Pc has an activated windows 8.1 license. And lockscreen features are usually disabled unless windows get activated

Comment: My PC has an activated windows 8.1 license too, but on my PC I always get this error and I don't know why?

Comment: Try creating a new account and running your code in that account if still not running then might be a registry issue.

Comment: Yes, it works. I tried on another PC and all works correctly.

Comment: Now I am really curious why it didnt work on your pc might be lockscreen registry issue or you might try in new account on your pc.